# Center Group Box

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm creating my first application in Visual C++ and for the life of me I cannot figure out to have the groupbox automatically center when the window is maximized. Right now the groupbox will only align to the left. How would I center it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't support automatic resizing / centering / justification, etc. for controls. You need to add a `WM_SIZE` handler for your dialog/window, and manually reposition the control whenever the parent client area changes.

Comment: @ Jonathan Potter, thanks for the information. I'm new to Visual C++ so I'll have to read up on `WM_SIZE` and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I'm assuming you are using a Visual C++ Windows Forms Application.

You will have to manually align it by adjusting the Left and Top properties of your control(s).  You can override the Resize event of the form so it will trigger when the size of the form is manipulated.  You can then use the width and height of the form to position your control in the center appropriately:

```
void myForm_Resize(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    myControl->Left = (myForm->Width - myControl->Width) / 2;
    myControl->Top = (myForm->Height - myControl->Height) / 2;
}
```

Comment: @ ruslander, I tried your suggestion, but it came up with some errors. I will work the code and see if I can get it working and get back.

Comment: Feel free to post some errors/exceptions and I can try to help diagnose.